# User has shared access to his personal account. How to revoke shared access to Google account technically?

Tags: rest, google-api, google-api-client, google-authentication

I can manage sharing access by user to his personal Google account via [Google OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2). But this article does not contain information how to revoke the access.

I need remove authorization (a user should not have to remove 'account' from Connected Apps in Google). Google has [special page](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) for this purpose. I need use same functionality in my application but I've not found developers instruction for this.

So how could I implement UI API for client in my application to provide himself to revoke his `OAuth2 token` (token shared by him from Google earlier)? May be some rest API for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways for revoke scopes authorization.

You can use the page you linked, about permissions, and manually remove the app.

Or you can use the [`token revoke`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) from Google. It's a GET request on this URL: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}`